# Nuxeo studio and custom UI possibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nuxeo

We're building a custom UI framework (Angular based) on top of the Nuxeo platform (Using REST API). Having said that, one of the requirements is to be able to use the dynamic workflow mechanism of the Nuxeo studio (I'm also not sure if content routing has a role on this).

Is it possible? What's the main idea/approach behind?

Also, if there are any resource or topic from the documentation please I need help with the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Workflow in Nuxeo Studio and deploy it on your Nuxeo server.

Then, if you build your WebApp using Angular on top of Nuxeo, it probably means you are using Automation http API.

You can then use the Automation Operations that are used to control the Workflow Service.
The dedicated operations are in the "Workflow Context" and "Routing" categories.

http://explorer.nuxeo.org/nuxeo/site/distribution/current/listOperations

We are currently working on adding a dedicated workflow REST endpoint like we did for documents, users, groups, directories : this will make the Angular binding even more natural.

Tiry

Comment: See http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/REST+API for a documentation about the REST endpoint.

Comment: You can also use the Nuxeo Angular SDK/Sample ?
https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-angular-sample

Comment: I'm exploring nuxeo and would like to build our own web interface to it. One thing that is not explain in the documentation albeit suggested is how can you build your own web ui to interact with nuxeo workflow and etc: what are the service provided by the nuxeo platform to plug your own web interface. How can you control the workflow etc ...